# Java client Speech to text real time stream migrating from V1 to V2

Tags: google-cloud-speech

`

Hi i am facing issues while migrating from V1 to V2 api,

i was using dependency as below in V1

```
`<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
  <version>1.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
  <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
</dependency>`
```

in my code i was using below

```
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.*;
```

and  following code

```
clientStream = client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);


RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16).setLanguageCode("en-US").setSampleRateHertz(16000)
 .build();

  StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig = StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
   .setConfig(recognitionConfig).setInterimResults(true).build();

 StreamingRecognizeRequest request = StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
  .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig).build();`
```

and send the continious stream as below

`

```
ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream;

StreamingRecognizeRequest request = StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data)).build();
        clientStream.send(request);`
```

now i want to update it to V2 api to version

`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
    <version>4.18.0</version>
</dependency>`
```

Seems StreamingRecognizeRequest is changes in V2

can any one please help in how to implement StreamingRecognizeRequest

Thanks
`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>26.25.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).